# How to animate a curve/circle for a tank

Tags: modifiers

I recently created a model of an M4A3 Sherman tank along with the tracks. I made the tracks first with a single plate and then used an array and had it follow a curve circle. This works well for a single render but I want to create an animation of it traveling over terrain. I need help mainly with finding a way to make the array of tracks follow the curve. Thanks in advance for any help. [image: The tracks separated from the model]

Answer (score 0):

If the tracks are arrayed along the curve, then keyframing the location of the track object should work. It's probably along the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Use a driver to move the curve along the curve's facing axis. I.e. the axis it points towards. Make sure you do not apply the curve modifier ever because that will prevent the array from following the curve.